# Codeigniter how to disable flashdata cache with database session handling?

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, session, caching

The problem is simple, but yet annoying. I use database sessions in Codeigniter, and I have many DB requests so I use database caching too.

I really like the flashdata feature, but it seems like it has an issue with the database caching.

**The flashdata when it's set it won't disappear until the database cache expires.**

I searched, but I didn't found any working solutions for this problem.

I really do not want to switch to native session handling, so anyone knows how to disable flashdata caching?

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem recently, but i was not using database session, my problem was, I wanted to cache page but not whole page, few sql queries should work as it is and few should give its cached data and I came up with some solution from Google :)

[This Link](http://jimdoescode.blogspot.in/2011/01/codeigniter-and-caching-love-hate.html) might help you to choose contents to cache.